# zerofree won't open filesystem

Tags: mount

I am trying to run zerofree on virtualbox .vdi disk. I attached the vdi disk to the storage to another virtual machine - debian desktop. I started the machine and mounted the hard disk with this command: mount -o ro /dev/sdb1 /home/user/mnt. But then if i try to run `zerofree /dev/sdb1/` i get `zerofree: failed to open filesystem /home/user/mnt/`

Why i am getting this error?

Comment: Hello and welcome to the U&L stack exchange site! Please review the [Help Center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) for information on how to best post on this site. You are receiving that error because the filesyste `/home/user/mnt/` does not exist at the location you specified in your command.

Comment: But it does exist:    

`vbox@debian:~$ mount | grep sdb1
/dev/sdb1 on /home/user/mnt type ext4 (ro,relatime,data=ordered)`

Comment: In your question you specify `/deb/sdb1` and in your comment your checking `/dev/sdb1` I assumed this was a typo but I want to be sure. You have the device mounted read only which you have to do with `zerofree` so I would check to see if are running the command with root(sudo) privileges and that you are specifying the device correctly and that it is mounted correctly.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. I tried something else and it worked. I tried this: `sudo zerofree /dev/sdb1` instead of `sudo zerofree /home/user/mnt/`.

Comment: i can accept my answer after two days.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found that this command works: `sudo zerofree /dev/sdb1`